# Proof verification: Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers bounded by $M\in\textbf{R}$, and which is also increasing. Then $a_{n}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of real numbers which has some finite upper bound
$M\in\textbf{R}$, and which is also increasing (i.e., $a_{n+1}\geq a_{n}$ for all $n \geq m$). Then $(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ is convergent, and in fact
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n} = \sup(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty} \leq M
\end{align*}

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $s = \sup(a_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$. We want to prove that, for any positive real number $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N\geq m$ such that $|a_{n} - s|\leq\varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$, which is equivalent to $s-\varepsilon < a_{n} < s + \varepsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$.

Indeed, according to the properties of the supremum, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $n_{0}$ such that $s - \varepsilon < a_{n_{0}}\leq s$.

Since $a_{n}$ is increasing, $s - \varepsilon < a_{n_{0}} < a_{n} \leq s < s + \varepsilon$ whenever $n > n_{0}$.

Consequently, we have proven that, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $n_{0}\geq m$ such that

$$|a_{n} - s|\leq\varepsilon$$

whenever $n\geq n_{0}$, and we are done.

Can someone double-check my argument?

Comment: Yes, looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mark indicated in a comment, and I also confirm, your argument is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1360429)

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari: I think the purpose of this answer is to remove the question from unanswered list. Hopefully the asker should accept it.